# How to add php-amqp in CircleCI config.yml?

Tags: php, circleci, php-amqp

I tried to add in my config.yml following command:

> docker-php-ext-install amqp

but CircleCI says:

> error: /usr/src/php/ext/amqp does not exist

This is my full config.yml file:

```
    # PHP CircleCI 2.0 configuration file
    #
    # Check https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/language-php/ for more details
    #
    version: 2
    jobs:
        build:
            docker:
                # specify the version you desire here
                - image: circleci/php:7.1-browsers

            # Specify service dependencies here if necessary
            # CircleCI maintains a library of pre-built images 4
            # documented at https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/circleci-images/
            # - image: circleci/mysql:9.4

            working_directory: ~/repo

    #        branches:
    #            only: master

            steps:
            - checkout

            # Download and cache dependencies
            - restore_cache:
                  keys:
                  - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "composer.json" }}
                  # fallback to using the latest cache if no exact match is found
                  - v1-dependencies-

            - run: sudo apt-get install -y libpng-dev libfreetype6-dev libjpeg-dev

            - run:
                name: Install PHP Extensions
                command: sudo docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-gd --with-jpeg-dir --with-png-dir --with-freetype-dir && sudo docker-php-ext-install gd && sudo docker-php-ext-install amqp

            - run: composer install -n --prefer-dist

            - save_cache:
                  paths:
                  - ./vendor
                  key: v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "composer.json" }}

            - run: mkdir var/data

            # run tests!
            - run: ./vendor/bin/simple-phpunit --log-junit ~/phpunit/junit.xml

            - store_test_results:
                path: ~/phpunit

            - store_artifacts:
                path: ~/phpunit

    workflows:
        version: 2

        build_tests:
            jobs:
            - build:
                filters:
                    branches:
                        only: master
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue:

```
- run:
    name: Install amqp extention
    command: curl -L -o /tmp/amqp.tar.gz https://pecl.php.net/get/amqp-1.9.3.tgz && tar xfz /tmp/amqp.tar.gz && rm -r /tmp/amqp.tar.gz && sudo mkdir -p /usr/src/php/ext/amqp && sudo mv amqp-1.9.3 /usr/src/php/ext/amqp && cd /usr/src/php/ext/amqp/amqp-1.9.3 && sudo phpize && sudo ./configure --with-amqp && sudo make && sudo make install && sudo cp -a /usr/src/php/ext/amqp/amqp-1.9.3/. /usr/src/php/ext/amqp/ && sudo docker-php-ext-install amqp
```

Full config for Symfony 4 project:

```
# PHP CircleCI 2.0 configuration file
#
# Check https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/language-php/ for more details
#
version: 2
jobs:
    build:
        docker:
            # specify the version you desire here
            - image: circleci/php:7.1-browsers

        # Specify service dependencies here if necessary
        # CircleCI maintains a library of pre-built images 4
        # documented at https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/circleci-images/
        # - image: circleci/mysql:9.4

        working_directory: ~/repo

#        branches:
#            only: master

        steps:
        - checkout

        # Download and cache dependencies
        - restore_cache:
              keys:
              - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "composer.json" }}
              # fallback to using the latest cache if no exact match is found
              - v1-dependencies-

        - run:
            name: Install pakaces
            command: sudo apt-get install -y libpng-dev libfreetype6-dev libjpeg-dev librabbitmq-dev

        - run:
            name: Install PHP Extensions
            command: sudo docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-gd --with-jpeg-dir --with-png-dir --with-freetype-dir && sudo docker-php-ext-install gd

        - run:
            name: Install amqp extention
            command: curl -L -o /tmp/amqp.tar.gz https://pecl.php.net/get/amqp-1.9.3.tgz && tar xfz /tmp/amqp.tar.gz && rm -r /tmp/amqp.tar.gz && sudo mkdir -p /usr/src/php/ext/amqp && sudo mv amqp-1.9.3 /usr/src/php/ext/amqp && cd /usr/src/php/ext/amqp/amqp-1.9.3 && sudo phpize && sudo ./configure --with-amqp && sudo make && sudo make install && sudo cp -a /usr/src/php/ext/amqp/amqp-1.9.3/. /usr/src/php/ext/amqp/ && sudo docker-php-ext-install amqp
#            && sudo make && sudo make install && sudo docker-php-ext-install amqp

        - run: composer install -n --prefer-dist

        - save_cache:
              paths:
              - ./vendor
              key: v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "composer.json" }}

        - run: mkdir var/data

        # run tests!
        - run: ./vendor/bin/simple-phpunit --log-junit ~/phpunit/junit.xml

        - store_test_results:
            path: ~/phpunit

        - store_artifacts:
            path: ~/phpunit

workflows:
    version: 2

    build_tests:
        jobs:
        - build:
            filters:
                branches:
                    only: master
```